# Asynchronous custom Dialog in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, modal-dialog, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to create a modal (asynchronous) dialog in a Windows Store App with custom content?

I know you can show a Message Dialog but only with some text and buttons. In my App I need to populate a Combo Box and let the user choose one of the items, before the rest of the code can be executed.

I already found something for a dialog which is not asynchronous (code is appended). It worked quite well until now. 
However, now I need to check again with the user if the chosen device is okay and somehow the Message Dialog is shown above the Dialog with the Combo Box.

Is there a (simple) way to "wait" for the result of my first Dialog?

Here the code of the custom popup I am using for my ComboBox Dialog:

```
public sealed partial class UsbSelectorPopup : UserControl {

    public IList<DeviceInformation> deviceList { get; set; }
    public int ChosenEntry { get; set; }

    public UsbSelectorPopup(IList<DeviceInformation> deviceList) {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.deviceList = deviceList;
        PopulateComboBox();
    }

    private void PopulateComboBox() {
        ...
    }

    public void OpenPopup() {
        this.ParentPopup.IsOpen = true;
        this.gdChild.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public void ClosePopup() {
        this.ParentPopup.IsOpen = false;
        this.gdChild.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void ChooseUsbBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ChosenEntry = UsbComboBox.SelectedIndex;
        ClosePopup();
    }

    private void CloseUsbBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ChosenEntry = 9999;
        ClosePopup();
    }
```

The Call in the MainPage:

```
// get all the USB Devices
var devices = ExamProvider.CustomStorageMedium.DeviceCollection;

// ask user which usb device to use
UsbSelectorPopup popup = new UsbSelectorPopup(devices);
popup.OpenPopup();

// get chosen device out of list
var chosenDevice = devices[popup.ChosenEntry];

// work with data on usb stick
 [...]

// ask user if he wants to continue with this device or choose another one
var result = await MessageBox.ShowAsync("You chose usb stick XYZ with file ABC on it. Do you want to continue?", MessageBoxButton.OkCancel);
```

(MessageBox is a simple Helper Class for calling MessageDialog)

### Solution

Thanks to Nate Diamond I knew what it was I should look for and so I found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12861824/2660864
I changed it a bit and surprisingly it now works!

UsbSelectorPopup:

```
// Property
public TaskCompletionSource<int> UsbChosenTask { get; set; }

// in the constructor:
UsbChosenTask = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

// In the Button Click Methods:
UsbChosenTask.TrySetResult(UsbComboBox.SelectedIndex);
```

The call:

```
UsbSelectorPopup popup = new UsbSelectorPopup(devices);
popup.OpenPopup();
var chosenEntry = await popup.UsbChosenTask.Task;
var chosenDevice = devices[popup.ChosenEntry];
```

Comment: One easy way to do this is with `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. What this lets you do is return a `Task<T>` (can be Task<object>) which only returns when you call `TaskCompletionSource<T>.SetResult(T result)`. This means that you can do all of your asynchronous processes and set the result (or set cancel/error) when you are done processing.

Comment: thanks for your comment. is it possible to provide an example how I can use the Tasks with my existing code? I already tried a bit but I don't have much experience with asynchronicity so I don't know exactly how I should approach my problem.

Comment: @NateDiamond you can add an answer if you like, I would accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do this is with TaskCompletionSource. What this lets you do is return a Task (can be Task) which only returns when you call TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(T result). This means that you can do all of your asynchronous processes and set the result (or set cancel/error) when you are done processing.

A quick example would be:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskCompletionSource;

private Task<bool> ShowAsync()
{
    //Do Show Stuff

    taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}

private void Close()
{
    //Do close stuff

    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

XAML has a popup control that is what you want.

```
<Popup x:Name="popup" IsOpen="True">
    <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=popup, Mode=OneWay}" 
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=popup, Mode=OneWay}">
        <!-- your content here -->
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Opacity=".25" />
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

In your code behind you can cause it to open and close by toggling the IsOpen property.

Make sense?

Best of luck.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. I already have the popup tag in my xaml. The main problem was, that I could not await the result of the popup and the MessageDialog called after the popup showed before the user could input something. The answer from Nate Diamond solved this problem.

Comment: There's always AsTask().Wait()