# Async wait for event after sending argument

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    moHost = new Host(
        APIServerType.Simulator,
        "T4Example",
        "112A04B0-5AAF-42F4-994E-FA7CB959C60B",
        "CTS",
        "myUser",
        "myPass");  //automated login

    moHost = Host.Login(
        APIServerType.Simulator,
        "T4Example",
        "112A04B0-5AAF-42F4-994E-FA7CB959C60B"); //manual login window
    moAccounts = moHost.Accounts;

    System.Console.WriteLine(moAccounts.ToString());
}
```

Where I know that the first automated login is an asynchronous request sent that I need to "wait" for.

And the login success would trigger:

```
public event Host.LoginSuccessEventHandler LoginSuccess
```

While a login failure would trigger:

```
public event Host.LoginFailureEventHandler LoginFailure
```

And a generic notification would be triggered by:

```
public event Host.NotificationEventHandler Notification
```

How do I go about handling this and properly waiting for my login success or failure?

The first automated login attempt does not show me as connected while the second manual login window indeed succeeds (therefore I am okay to think my credentials are fine and now its just that the code didn't properly 'wait').

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858501/is-it-possible-to-await-an-event-instead-of-another-async-method Does this solve your problem? I think it does.

Comment: @usr sorry to do this, but would you mind painting the picture a little more for me? i am unsure exactly how to implement what is recommended.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to wrap the events that can trigger from `Host.Login`, and use it as an Extension Method around the `Host` type:

```
public static class HostExtensions
{
    public static Task<bool> LoginAsync(this Host host, APIServerType serverType, string name, string id)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        try
        {
            host.LoginSuccess += (object obj, LoginSuccessEventHandler e) =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            }
            
            host.LoginFailure += (object obj, LoginFailureEventHandler e) =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tcs.SetException(e);
        }
        
        host.Login(serverType, name, id);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

If the notification message is important, you can create a `LoginDetails` sort of type an use it as the return type of the `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
public class LoginDetails
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Notification { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
public static Task<LoginDetails> LoginAsync(this Host host, APIServerType serverType, string name, string id)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<LoginDetails>();
    var loginDetails = new LoginDetails();
    try
    {
        host.LoginSuccess += (object obj, LoginSuccessEventHandler e) =>
        {
            loginDetails.IsSuccess = true;
            tcs.SetResult(loginDetails);
        }
        
        host.LoginFailure += (object obj, LoginFailureEventHandler e) =>
        {
            loginDetails.IsSuccess = false;
            tcs.SetResult(loginDetails);
        }
        
        host.Notification += (object obj, NotificationEventHandler e) =>
        {
            loginDetails.Notificaiton = e.Notification // I assume it would look something like this
            tcs.SetResult(loginDetails);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tcs.SetException(e);
    }
    
    host.Login(serverType, name, id);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

And now you can use `await` on `LoginAsync`.

```
var login = await host.LoginAsync(APIServerType.Simulator, "T4Example", "112A04B0-5AAF-42F4-994E-FA7CB959C60B");
```

On a side note, if you use this inside a `Console` application you would have to use `Result` which will *block* rather than `await` (which yields control back to the caller) inside `Main`, which is a bit of a shame since it would be missing the whole point of asynchronous calls:

```
var login = host.LoginAsync(APIServerType.Simulator, "T4Example", "112A04B0-5AAF-42F4-994E-FA7CB959C60B").Result;
```

Comment: hello there are some errors in this code. `return tcs.Task;` for example tells me that `a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression`. any idea?

Comment: Fixed my code. The methods should return a `Task<bool>` or a `Task<LoginDetails>` respectively

Comment: thank you i will look this weekend sorry for not accepting yet. thank you very much for taking the time to adjust the code.

Comment: Don't you need to add an await for the return ?  (return await tcs.Task;)