# Forcing web request to wait for an event callback

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, callback, httphandler

I have a web request (`HttpRequest`) which triggers a third library scanning method on my server that has an event handler attached to it:

```
scanner.OnScanComplete += scanner_OnScanComplete;
```

The web request will invoke `scanner.Scan(files)` but how can I force (or hook) the request to wait and get the results from `scanner_OnScanComplete` when the scan process is complete so it can return data to clients without having to send another web request to get this data?

```
void DoWork(HttpRequst request, var files)
{
 var scanner = new Scanner()
 scanner.OnScanComplete += scanner_OnScanComplete;
 scan(files)

}

void scanner_OnScanComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  var scanCompleted = true;

  //Return scanCompleted somehow to the DoWork thread above
}
```

Comment: This isn't real code so hard to help! `new Scanner` with no parenthesis?! How does `request` get used etc? What is `Scanner` and how does `OnScanComplete` work etc?!

Comment: There is no real code, request is not being used, this is what im trying to figure out, i just put this as a an example to what i need to do why is this difficult to understand?

Comment: I added the parenthesis, now you can figure out what the code does?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a HttpHandler or can you use other api's?

If you can use MVC4 or later then you can use an asynchronous Action Method to do this easily. [Look here for an example of how to use them](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

In addition to using an async Action Method you may need a way to await the event from the scanner. Using a Task Completion source as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12858633/30366) may be a good way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you want is to store the completion of the task in a boolean member.
The boolean shall be marked `volatile` to avoid threading issues.

The risk of the approach is to lead to timeouts on client side if the scan processing is too long.

```
private volatile bool _finished;

void DoWork(HttpRequst request, var files)
{
    var scanner = new Scanner();
    scanner.OnScanComplete += scanner_OnScanComplete;

    _finished= false;
    scan(files)

    while (!_finished)    // wait for the scan completion
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // avoid consuming 100% cpu

    var scanData = Dothescanwork();
    //Return scanData somehow to the DoWork thread above
}

void scanner_OnScanComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _finished= true; 
}
```

Comment: This will lock the thread that performs the request. While this is a possible option, it is not recommended.

Comment: @RuneGrimstad It seems it's what she intended to do at first. No doubt there's a nicer way to do it.