# Implementing Console.ReadLine in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm trying to create an app with C# WPF to simulate Windows' command prompt, but with more flexibility and output options (like displaying images or forms). I recently got stuck on trying to simulate `Console.ReadLine()`. I need to keep the GUI fully responsive, allowing the user to type input. At the same time, I need to be able to `return` the answer from the same method.

I tried to solve this problem already by using events, but I can't figure out how to use them in a way that won't return `void`. I looked into `async` / `await` and a [question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858501/is-it-possible-to-await-an-event-instead-of-another-async-method), but couldn't quite figure out how to use that information. I considered an event-driven solution where the result would be stored in a permanent list variable for all of the inputs, which I could read the last of to get the latest input, but decided it wasn't good enough for what I'm simulating.

I plan on creating the console GUI in the main thread as soon as the application starts. However, I will be using logic from it in another thread which will be the meat of my code (I know it's not a professional way to program, but this is a personal project / learning experience, after all.) Then, I want to use some sort of custom `ReadLine()` method to wait until the user submits text, then return it. If this is possible, how can it be done in WPF?

Comment: So, you want another thread to handle the console GUI, what about the main thread? what will it be doing? Displaying some WPF window?

Comment: @YacoubMassad oh, I wrote that wrong. Thanks for noticing so quickly. Fixed.

Comment: So, ReadLine will be called on a background thread? And when you call it, do expect that it should block (wait) until the user writes something and hits enter?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal. I know that it means using the console requires the user to create a new thread in order to call `Read` the way it's intended, but I don't actually know a cleaner way to handle that. (It's another issue for another time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following quick and dirty code should give you an idea how to achieve what you want:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var console = new MyConsole();
        this.Content = console.Gui;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var read = console.ReadLine();
            console.WriteLine(read);
        });
    }
}

public class MyConsole {
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _readLineSignal;
    private string _lastLine;        
    public MyConsole() {
        _readLineSignal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Gui = new TextBox();
        Gui.AcceptsReturn = true;
        Gui.KeyUp += OnKeyUp;
    }

    private void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        // this is always fired on UI thread
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter) {
            // quick and dirty, but that is not relevant to your question
            _lastLine = Gui.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();
            // now, when you detected that user typed a line, set signal
            _readLineSignal.Set();
        }
    }        

    public TextBox Gui { get; private set;}

    public string ReadLine() {
        // that should always be called from non-ui thread
        if (Gui.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            throw new  Exception("Cannot be called on UI thread");
        // reset signal
        _readLineSignal.Reset();
        // wait until signal is set. This call is blocking, but since we are on non-ui thread - there is no problem with that
        _readLineSignal.WaitOne();
        // we got signalled - return line user typed.
        return _lastLine;
    }

    public void WriteLine(string line) {
        if (!Gui.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) {
            Gui.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => WriteLine(line)));
            return;
        }

        Gui.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Here is how I see it could be done:

```
public class MyConsole
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> m_Lines = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    public string ReadLine()
    {
        return m_Lines.Take();
    }

    private void AddNewLine(string new_line)
    {
        m_Lines.Add(new_line);
    }

    //...
}
```

The AddNewLine method is a private method that you must call when the user writes something and hits enter. This happens in the GUI thread.

The ReadLine method is a public method that your other thread will call to get a new line.

Please note that this call will return a stored item if there is any, or it will wait until a new item is added by the AddNewLine method. This blocking is a feature of the BlockingCollection class.

Comment: I'm trying to write to the console, then read from it, and write what I read. When I write to the console (currently in App.xaml.cs), it appears. If I try to read from App.xaml.cs, it blocks the application since it's on the GUI thread. Threads, ThreadPool, Dispatcher / BackgroundWorkers don't appear to let me circumvent this: Either the Read() never gets called or, when the second Write() is on the GUI thread, it simply goes to that because Read() is asynchronous. See my code: http://pastebin.com/BJdxh8Gk

I can't debug it either because once the code hits Read(), the debugger can't follow.

Comment: Why in your Read method, you reinitialize the blocking collection to a new one?

Comment: If it only blocks when the list is empty, I only want to store up to 1 element so I can use its blocking feature. Otherwise, Read would only work once correctly, right? Since there's no `.Clear()` method, I just overwrote the list.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've implemented Evk's solution at the moment, and it seems to be working fine. It's always nice to learn new things, though :)

Comment: You're welcome. Good to hear your problem is solved.