# get callback value from action

Tags: c#

I have this function with action parameter, after it was executed the parameter on that function will have a value. Is there a way for me to get the value?

```
public void DetailsAsync(string param1, string param2,Action<IList<Detail>> callback)
{
       //process happen here and will have a callback to produce the data for detail
}

public class DetailController:ApiController
{
  private IList<Detail> details;

  private DetailCompleted(IList<Detail> detail)
  {
    //now detail parameter has a value that I can use
    details = detail;
  }


  [HttpGet]
  public IList<Detail> GetDetails()
  {
    ServiceManager.DetailsAsync("param1","param2",detailsCompleted)

   //after ServiceManager.DetailsAsync it will go to return details
    return details;
  }
}
```

When I tried this code, I placed a breakpoint on return details and breakpoint on detailsCompleted but what happen is that when I called the web api GetDatails, it will first execute return details and right after that it will execute detailsCompleted function. that's why currently I cant get the value.

Comment: Overall,this looks like a correct callback pattern to me, but I have some concerns over why some things contain the word "async" in their names.  I suspect there may be some important code missing.  Can you share the code inside `DetailsAsync`?

Comment: @BradleyUffner unfortunately I don't have the code for it, all I know is the parameter required to use DetailsAsync but I think they are calling a service with async inside of it.

Comment: @BradleyUffner actually when set a breakpoint in DetailCompleted, the detail has the record I need, but since the "return details" was being executed first instead of DetailCompleted my details variable doesn't get the records.

Comment: That's what I suspected.  You need some way to delay execution of the `return` statement until signaled by `DetailCompleted` that a result has been received.  A `Semaphore`, or `TaskCompletionSource` would work, but may be a little tricky to set up.  The real problem is that `DetailsAsync` is implemented with a poor async pattern.

Comment: @BradleyUffner my understanding is that Semaphore or TaskCompletionSource can be implemented in void like DetailAsync right? since I dont have access on the code of DetailsAsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way `DetailsAsync` is written, you will need some sort of signalling system to pause execution of `GetDetails` until the callback is fired.  There are several [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives), but I choose an [`AutoResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=netframework-4.7.2) because it is fairly simple to work with and understand.

(I've changed some of the return types just so that I didn't have to create fake classes to match your code)

```
public class DetailController
{
    private IList<int> details;
    private AutoResetEvent callbackSignal = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private void DetailCompleted(IList<int> detail)
    {
        details = detail;
        callbackSignal.Set();
    }    

    public IList<int> GetDetails()
    {    
        ServiceManager.DetailsAsync("param1", "param2", DetailCompleted);
        callbackSignal.WaitOne();
        return details;
    }
}
```

`callbackSignal.WaitOne();` will block until "signaled".  In the callback method, `callbackSignal.Set();` sends the signal, telling anything waiting on the event that it is ok to proceed now.

Without knowing exactly how `DetailsAsync` is implemented, I can't guarantee that this will work, but I'm hopeful.  You may also have to add some additional protection to make sure this is full reentrant if required.

---

If you would rather work with the more modern `async` / `await` pattern, you could wrap access to `DetailsAsync` access in a method that is `Task` returning, and uses a `TaskCompletionSource` to orchestrate the callback and return values.

```
public class DetailController
{
    public async Task<IList<int>> GetDetails()
    {
        var details = await ServiceWrapper.GetDetails();
        return details;
    }
}

public static class ServiceWrapper
{
    public static Task<IList<int>> GetDetails()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<int>>();
        ServiceManager.DetailsAsync("param1", "param2", (IList<int> details) =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(details);
            });
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, i tried it but its like taking forever, until now it's still running.

Comment: I've added an example of the `TaskCompletionSource` pattern, which might work better for your specific case.

Comment: woooowwwww!!!!, thanks a lot Bradley, your code for TaskCompletionSource did work!!! it took me the whole day!!! thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

The return value of a `Action<T>` is by default void. If you want a return value, you should use `Func<T,TResult>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks and yes I agree with you, the problem is that, I'm only allowed to create my own web api function and use ServiceManager object to get the records and As I mention I'm confused also on why the return details was being hit first and followed by DetailCompleted function.

Comment: When you say "by default void", do you mean that it can ever be non-void?

Comment: He is using a callback to "return" the data.  There is no need to convert the method to a `Func` for that to work.

Comment: @pteberf it can not be non-void, I think I actually meant to say "by definition"

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes I think you're right, I misunderstood the question. The answer of pteberf is correct

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that `DetailsAsync()`, as implied by name is asynchronous and you return details before waiting for results of `DetailsAsync()`.
So you should `await` it, but because `DetailsAsync` returns `void`, you can't.

So you could wrap the `DetailsAsync` in a Task and `.Wait()` for it, but it kind of sucks because you will block the calling thread.

```
[HttpGet]
public IList<Detail> GetDetails()
{
    Task.Run(() => 
        ServiceManager.DetailsAsync("param1", "param2", detailsCompleted)
    ).Wait();
    return details;
}
```

Comment: I apologize for not so clear explanation, the ServiceManager.DetailAsync is void and inside of it I think they are calling async function that's why I think they named it DetailAsync

Comment: Well if they are calling an async function inside and await for it, chances are DetailsAsync is async too. `async` methods can return `void` too.

Comment: @pteberf but when I tried to implement the code you gave, it says an error "cannot await void"

Comment: If `DetailsAsync` is implemented as I suspect, awaiting it won't help.  What is the origin of `DetailsAsync`?  Is it part of some public package, or is it internally written code that you just do not have access to?

Comment: @BradleyUffner it's internally written code which I don't have access.

Comment: I think you might have to use a Semaphore here, as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858501/is-it-possible-to-await-an-event-instead-of-another-async-method

Comment: @pteberf when I tried it, it says "cannot convert from void to System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>"

Comment: @Amfasis I don't know it but I'll check the details of it thanks

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure that `DetailsAsync` isn't implemented correctly.  The semaphore that @Amfasis mentioned may work.  A `TaskCompletionSource` might also be a good option.

Comment: @pteberf yes it did run but the same thing happen, the code execution will go first in "return details" before going to ``` private DetailCompleted(IList<Detail>detail) that's why the details variable is still null

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'm not sure if DetailsAsync is not properly implemented, but using the said function actually gave me the records but the problem is that I can't get the records to be passed on another variable ```details

Comment: Yeah.. :( Nothing inside the `DetailsAsync` signals that the task is complete because there is no task. So you have to take care of this externally like @BradleyUffner and @Amfasis suggest.